# Verificar se email está cadastrado no BD

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou fazendo uma busca em meu BD para verificar a existência de e-mail, evitando o cadastro do mesmo novamente, mas estou com problema no retorno, o script abaixo envia e trata o retorno.

```
 if (sender.getFieldName() == 'Email') {
 if (sender.getValue()) {

     var emailExist = false;

     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'AjaxBasedValidation.php',
         data: {
             checkEmail: sender.getValue()
         },
         async: false, 
         dataType: 'json',           
         success: function(dataResult) {
             emailExist = dataResult;
         }
     });

     editors['Email']
         .setState(emailExist ? 'warning' : 'success')
         .setHint(emailExist ? 'E-mail ' + sender.getValue() + ' já está cadastrado' : null);
 } else {
     editors['Email']
         .setState('normal')
         .setHint(null);
 }
```

}

O código que verifica no BD:

```
    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_GET['checkEmail'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
    $con = mysqli_connect(".", "", "", "");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `Email` = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

    if($rcQuery == true){
        die('{"dataResult" : 0"}'); 
    } else {
        die('{"dataResult" : 1"}');
    }
```

Todos os e-mails que informo o script está acusando que já estão cadastrados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conte o número de linhas retornadas pela consulta com `mysqli_num_rows()`. Veja que no if a comparação é feita com uma variável que não existe no código da pergunta `$rcQuery`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `Email` = '{$emailPostado}'");
$retorno['dataResult'] = ($result) ? mysqli_num_rows($result) : 0;
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: Olá @rray, eu editei a pergunta depois da sua resposta, obrigado pela dica,  vou testar.

Comment: @adventistapr lembre de converter o retorno do ajax em json, `var retorno = JSON.parse(dataResult)`, depois pode usar.  `console.log(retorno.dataRresult);`

Comment: Olá @rray, poderia me dar um exemplo de como  converter o retorno do ajax em json? Fiz do modo que me passou, mas não sei se fiz certo. Agradeço.

Comment: @adventistapr o que aconteceu:? deu erro?

Comment: Olá @rray, ainda continua acusando que todos e-mail já estão cadastrados

Comment: @adventistapr no javascript se vc fizer `console.log(dataResult);` mostra o que?

Comment: Olá @rray, valeu pela ajuda, refiz a busca e debuguei o script, agora está tudo correto.
Estava errando no retorno do php, valeu pelas dicas.

Comment: @adventistapr tranquilo ;) q bom q acertou o código

Answer (score 1):

Sei que essa pergunta já foi respondida, mas gostaria de deixar uma solução mais segura no caso de instruções sql voltadas para consultas de strings:

No caso do seu select ficaria mais seguro executar as consultas de emails da seguinte maneira:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `Email` LIKE \"%".$emailPostado."%\"");
```

Outra coisa, procure estudar sobre a classe [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php), pois estas funções do php mysql_* e mysqli_* estão obsoletas e já não existem mais a partir da versão 7 do php.

Comment: Grande dica @Rafael Andrade, muito obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado @adventistapr, prazer em ajudá-lo!